# Font Awesome being blocked for IE9 users on customer site

Tags: azure, firewall, font-awesome, eot

I have deployed an MVC4 application that is hosted on Windows Azure that uses Font Awesome for several of the icons. A customer has reported that these are not displaying for them on IE9 although I have checked this from the website on our computers using IE9 and this seems to be fine. Is it possible that the EOT file extension could be getting blocked by the customers firewall?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? We are having the EXACT same problem.

Comment: Ensure that the mime types for the extension are added to the webserver in IIS, this is EOT for pre IE9 and WOFF I believe